How to create a "gamut" diagram using chart.js
Do you have any ideas on how to create such charts?


Of course, the background can be set... but then these squares, dots in different colors, triangle line.
Do you have any ideas on how to utilize existing chart.js plugins? There's always the option to create something new, but perhaps something like this already exists?
I've looked through the list of charts at https://github.com/chartjs/awesome?tab=readme-ov-file#charts, but I don't really see anything similar.

OK, I found the answer... although it could probably be further improved, generally it can be done using a bubble graph... points can have different shapes (squares, circles) and sizes... so everything fits here... additionally, on this graph, I draw a linear graph that will outline a triangle...
Maybe someone will find it useful in the future :)
